# BLE経由でandroidからLEDを制御したいが、再接続の方法が分かりません

Tags: android, bluetooth

androidアプリ開発をしています。初心者です、よろしくお願いします。

自作のハード上の**LEDをBLE経由でandroid(Nexus5)から制御したい**のですが、
一度接続が切れると、再接続ができません。なぜなのでしょうか、、

公式サンプルの「BluetoothLeGatt」を使用しています。
status:disconnectの状態でconnectを押した後のlogcatは以下の通りです：

D/BluetoothLeService﹕ Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.
clientConnect() - address=[device address(大文字)], isDirect=false
btif_get_address_type: Device [device address(小文字)] address type 0
btif_get_device_type: Device [device address(小文字)] type 2
device already in iniator white list

もし、情報が足りない部分がありましたら、加筆致します。
よろしくお願いします。